# Lightning component not taking input from design attributes

Tags: lightning-aura-components

This lightning component does not respond to attribute fieldsArray. Component on detail page of account does not display exactly those fields which i enter in value of attribute fieldsArray. I am using Compact layout. Can anyone point out why :

```
Component

<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,
                            force:hasSObjectName" access="global">

    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" default="" />
    <aura:attribute name="sObjectName" type="String" default="Account" />
    <aura:attribute name="numberOfColumns" type="String" default="2" />
    <aura:attribute name="fieldsArray" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute name="layoutType" type="String" default="Compact" />

    <lightning:card iconName="custom:custom19" title="lightning:recordForm in Spring'18">

        <div class="slds-p-left_large slds-p-right_medium">

            <lightning:recordForm aura:id="recordViewForm"
                                  recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                                  objectApiName="{!v.sObjectName}"
                                  fields="{!v.fieldsArray}"
                                  layoutType="{!v.layoutType}"
                                  columns="{!v.numberOfColumns}"
                                  onsuccess="{!c.raiseTheToastMessage}" />
        </div>

    </lightning:card>
</aura:component>


Design file

<design:component>
    <design:attribute name="sObjectName" label="Object" datasource = "Account, Contact, Opportunity" description="object on whose detail page component should be available" />
    <design:attribute name="numberOfColumns" label="Columns" datasource="1,2,3,4" description="Number of columns component should have" />
    <design:attribute name="fieldsArray" label="Field List" description="comma separated list of fields" />    
    <design:attribute name="layoutType" label="Layout" datasource = "Custom, Full, Compact" description="type of layout to be used in component" />    
</design:component>


JS Controller


({
    raiseTheToastMessage : function(component, event, helper) {
        var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
        toastEvent.setParams({
            "title": "Success!",
            "message": "The record has been updated successfully.",
            "type": "success"
        });
        toastEvent.fire();
    }
})
```

I am choosing Compact Layout.

Comment: What is the exact issue can you please explain more about it. As I copied the same code and it is working fine. Also, if possible add the screenshot of the issue because one picture is worth of 100 words.

Comment: Component on detail page of account does not display exactly those fields which i enter in value of attribute fieldsArray.

Comment: Do not specify `sObjectName` as a design attribute as this attribute is populated automatically when you implement `force:hasSObjectName`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the problem is that the fields attribute should be array of strings as documented:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:recordForm/specification

so fix the component:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,
                            force:hasSObjectName" access="global">

    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" default="" />
    <aura:attribute name="sObjectName" type="String" default="Account" />
    <aura:attribute name="numberOfColumns" type="String" default="2" />
    <aura:attribute name="fieldsArray" type="String[]" />
    <aura:attribute name="layoutType" type="String" default="Compact" />

    <lightning:card iconName="custom:custom19" title="lightning:recordForm in Spring'18">

        <div class="slds-p-left_large slds-p-right_medium">

            <lightning:recordForm aura:id="recordViewForm"
                                  recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                                  objectApiName="{!v.sObjectName}"
                                  fields="{!v.fieldsArray}"
                                  layoutType="{!v.layoutType}"
                                  columns="{!v.numberOfColumns}"
                                  onsuccess="{!c.raiseTheToastMessage}" />
        </div>

    </lightning:card>
</aura:component>
```

Comment: Encountered two issues: 1. i could not define datasource value for design:attribute after converting to String[] as datasource can be defined only for String types and not for String[]. 2.String[] is not compatible the interfaces implemented in <aura:component>.

Comment: for fixing the first issue - use a different attribute for your `design` attribute and on init copy the values in the controller. I did not understand the second issue

Comment: i think second issue error was saying that attribute of type String[] is not compatible with interfaces flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome.